# Is there a limit definition for the roots of a polynomial with arbitrary degree?

Tags: polynomials

I know there's no general formula for all the roots of a polynomial with a degree greater than 4, but is there some sort of limit (or other) definition to calculate the roots (particularly the largest root)?

Comment: There are lots of known bounds on the roots of a given polynomial. See the Wikipedia article on "Properties of polynomial roots, section on "Bounds on (complex) polynomial roots".

Comment: Is your goal numerical computation? Or do you just want to express the largest root of a polynomial as a limit for theoretical purposes (for instance, you are looking for a proof strategy)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For computing the largest root, see the [Graeffe Method.](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Graeffe's_method)

For bounding the largest root, there are many bounds, see [the Wikipedia article](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Properties_of_polynomial_roots) (which is incomplete, but since you don't tell us what you want, maybe that's good enough).